# I can't execute my application with phonegap

Tags: android, windows, gradle, terminal, phonegap

I am new in Phonegap world and I'm getting some issues with Android emulator. I read everything on the web but nothing seems to work.

Once I have created my phonegap app, I try to execute the command:

`phonegap run android`

I'm getting this error message:

`Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio, or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle in your path, or install Android Studio`

I have already installed Android Studio but I still get this error. What can I do? Thank you very much for your help!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F5Wn.png)

Comment: Can you try adding the android to the path variable. This would be the path where your Android SDK or gradle is installed. Get the path and put in: start > search environment variables > user path > add new

Comment: I put C:\gradle-6.6-bin\gradle-6.6\bin in the PATH variable, both fors system and user variables... but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you try setting you ANDROID_SDK_ROOT?

Comment: I have just did it. After I set that variable everything stopped woking, so I closed the terminal and opened it again. Now I am getting this error: "Failed to install apk to device: Performing Push Install
C:\Users\Vicentini\myapp\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 177.8 MB/s (6067159 bytes in 0.033s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]"

Comment: @VasanthaGaneshK thank you for editing my question. Now it's easier to read, can you tell me how did you manage to do that?

Comment: You can use markdown in stackoverflow. [Here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet) is a cheatsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue. I updated the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT path, SDKs through Android Studio, and minSDK version in the config file of my project. Now everything is working. Then I deleted all my emulators and created new ones.